# Gathering/reading data from sensors on two different baud rates with Arduino

Tags: arduino

I want to use an Arduino to gather data from two sensors. This seems easy when the required baud rate for two sensors is the same. However, I'm stumped as how to go about doing this when two different rates are required.

For example, suppose I want to use [a barometer](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/253) and [a GPS sensor](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/176) at the same time. I imagine I'd have to modify something lower-level for one of the sensors (possibly in the libraries or supporting functions), but where do I begin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a look at the provided material, I can see that your hardware use serial communications. The barometer uses an [I²C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) port and the GPS a serial port.

The "communication speed" (or baud rate) does not have to be exactly the same for all devices. Indeed, your sensors may have different sample rate or different needs, and thus does not need to communicate with the central unit with the same frequency.

I would suggest to go step by step. Try first with the GPS sensor. I think serial ports are easier to start with. Try first (a) to communicate directly with the GPS through your computer (you can use your Arduino to set up a USB-serial connection), and later (b) try to write some code which communicates in the same way with the GPS but now from Arduino.

Answer (score 1):

Simple method for Doing this. You have two Serial Port

1. SoftwareSerial
2. hardwareserial

In software Serial is one You communicate Directly . in hardware serial you configured for particular pin as Tx and Rx pin. SO barometer you can use SoftwareSerial and for GPS you can use Hardware Serial.

```
[1]: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial
  [2]: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=49645.0
```